# .hbs file in node.js vs front-end framework like vue or react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, web, backend

Please explain what's best for production work with pros and corns.

1. using .hbs file or
2. using the front-end framework like react or vue.js?

I think we can use vue or react in the hbs file. However, I want to know what's the best practice. Thanks